# Can I use in global box-sizing:border-box in my project?

Tags: html, css, border-box, box-sizing

Can I use in my all  murkup (all project ) `box-sizing: border-box;`?

for example:

```
html { 
   box-sizing: border-box; 
}, 
:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit; 
}
```

Because it is easier to count the real width, but are there any downsides to this approach?

Answer (score 15):

I generally apply it to everything. Use:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

It makes every the g a lot easier and is widely supported.

https://css-tricks.com/international-box-sizing-awareness-day/

http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

### Edit

It's also worth noting that the CSS working group consider this a mistake in the design of CSS:

> Box-sizing should be border-box by default.

https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/mistakes

Answer (score 4):

Using this is much beneficial

```
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
      box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

You can easily override it by applying specific CSS to any element.

Just for knowledge... Bootstrap also uses this technique.

IE6 and IE7 does not support this as per [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
html * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and it's working very well for me.

Comment: You should also make sure to apply it to pseudo elements, see my answer.